# Python imaplib, fetch unseen uids after uid

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I want to fetch unseen UIDs greater than a given UID. I'm trying to do:

`result, numbers = server.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN', str(minUID) + ':*')`

but that doesn't work properly. For `1:*` I get all unseen UIDs correctly, but for `minUID:*` I'm only getting  the latest unseen UID.

I know I can do a `server.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN')` and then filter it for `>minUID` but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Add the UID key before: UNSEEN UID minuid:*.  You are searching for a sequence number larger tha. The given UID which will never happen.

Comment: I'm using the uid function, it translates to UID UNSEEN minuid:*

Comment: Yes, you need it twice:  the first UID asks for UID output.  The second one indicates UID input:  `UID SEARCH UNSEEN UID 23:*`

Comment: ah ok. I'll try that out

Answer (score 1):

To search with both unseen and uid greater than 23

```
result, numbers = server.uid("search", None, '(UNSEEN UID 23:*)')
```